# Install SQL server 2008 R2 with VS 2010

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio

Ok, I've installed SQL Server 2008 R2.

I'm trying to add a "SQL Server Database" to an ASP MVC project.

But it keeps telling me I need SQL Server for it to work.
What do I need to do to setup the SQL Server properly for it to work with VS2010 ?

I've tried messing with the SQL Server Management Studio, and can't seem to connect to anything through there.

What am I doing wrong ? How can I create a working SQL service ?

Comment: restart server machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to your SQL Server Configuration Manager. You will find it in the SQL Server folder, under Configuration Tools.

Check the list of services that are currently running. At the minimum you should have started "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)" (if it's the default instance).

After you check that, go to the client and to the server protocols and see if the TCP/IP and Shared Memory protocols are enabled. If yes, then you should be set for the first time use of SQL Server.

Open Management Studio and try to connect to the local instance: use local machine name or IP.
If it won't work, please tell us any error that you might get.

Comment: Thanks, problem was I didn't have service instance at all. Needed to  reinstall (5th time) and  then it created it finally